# Device Driver proc entry ownership

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver

I am a newbye in Device Driver and I am struggling with a /sys/class/net/atm0/statistics/* problem, I would like now which module is owner of that entry, there is a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance, 
pedr0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually looking at sysfs, not procfs.

In any case, working from a similar example on my system:

```
# cd /sys/class/net/wlan0
# cd ../
# ls -lah
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 May 24 19:19 wlan0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlan0
# cd ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/
# ls -lah 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 24 19:19 driver -> ../../../../bus/pci/drivers/iwlwifi
# cd driver
# ls -lah
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 May 30 19:17 module -> ../../../../module/iwlwifi
```

On my system wlan0 is managed by the iwlwifi module.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I am working in a different env but I solved my issues, great!